# Can someone ID this brand of a drop bar?

Tags: drop-bar

[image: the only logo of the dropbar and nothing else]Its a t6 alloy compact dropbar and the specs are engraved in the bar ends. It's the only logo available and its like laser etched so it could be that the old logos could have worn off before I got it.

Comment: Doesn't look like one of the common brands. Extra information like the brand of the bike, time when it was bought, where in the world it is etc could be useful.

Comment: Sadly this is a part that I just got from a friend and totally different from the parts of the bike since I mostly bought and assembled it. I'm at SEA and couldn't find the logo anywhere.

Comment: Southeast Asia (did I understand it right?) is already helpful if someone wants to play detective. At least it means it's very unlikely that it's an European house brand.

Comment: can you try to shine light on it to see if there are any 'shadows' or 'imprints' caused by the faded decals giving a weathering difference on the covered and uncovered surface?

Comment: Is there something special about this handlebar that you need to know the manufacturer? Because they're commodity parts.

Comment: have you taken off the bar tape to check the stamps at the end of the bar? do that.

Comment: No weathered imprints as far as I can scan through the bars and the stamps on the end are just the length and size of the dropbar and what material it was made. Am trying to know what it is since I'll be selling off this bike and I need to list every part. This is the only one I don't know the model and brand of.

Comment: If this was an OEM part on a new bike, the bike brand would just list the material and width. I think ad for second hand bike doesn't need more detail.

Answer (score 3):

To me this looks like half the logo of the [Pryde Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Pryde) also called Neil Pryde:

[image]

The main company only sells Kites and Windsurfing equipment now.

"Please note that NeilPryde Bikes is a licensed product and isn’t traded via NeilPryde windsurf / waterwear & accessories." from [their FAQ](https://www.neilpryde.com/pages/general-faq). I am not entirely certain what to make of that. They apparently moved production to the UK and print the name on the frame tubes and not the logo.
[Source](https://www.cyclingweekly.com/reviews/road-bikes/neilpryde-bura-sl)

Comment: the logo is used on the bikes (check image search) so it's a good call. The handlebar without doubt just a rebranded product anyway/

Comment: Oh dang great find. Thanks looks like imma check it more. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

This expands on a comment by @ojs and the OP.

You indicated in a comment that you want to sell the bike and are looking to produce an informative listing. It's a good thought! However, if the bar is actually OEM, this could be tricky. To be clear, when ojs and I say "OEM", we mean handlebars (or other components) that have the bike manufacturer's brand (or a generic brand) on them, but were made by someone else. OEM stands for original equipment manufacturer; many of us probably know the phrase from cars, but the phenomenon occurs in other industries, and bikes are an example.

By contrast, a bike might have come with handlebars with a recognizable brand. For example, my old 2002 Giant TCR came stock with a 3T bar (a Forma, I think). I have a different bike with a Zipp SL70 handlebar. The relevant measurements could be looked up, assuming you remember the model name, and assuming the information is still out there. For example, I can't find the drop and reach specifications for the Forma, and indeed, I'm not sure in those days that it was common to provide drop and reach numbers.

### Key handlebar measurements

Pulling some graphics from [this road.cc article](https://road.cc/content/buyers-guide/10-best-road-and-gravel-cycling-drop-handlebars-288541), if you want to be thorough, you could easily measure the handlebar width from center to center, either where the brake hoods are mounted or at the ends of the drops (marked in the pic below). On most bars, those measurements are identical. Actually, in the picture, these bars have a bit more of a complex shape (specifically, the drops are flared), so the handlebar is wider at the drops than on the hoods. In any case, the width is probably the first thing you'd look at, and it's the only thing many people would look at. Common widths are 40, 42, and 44cm.

[image]

If you want, you can try to measure the drop and reach, or how deep and how long the bars go respectively. I believe this isn't as important for a used bike, especially if it's not a super high-end one. Additionally, these will probably be difficult to measure by hand. If you are determined, you can probably get close to the actual dimensions with just a tape measure. Again, consider this entirely optional info.

[image]

### A word on OEM arrangements

I'm under the impression that today, many or most bikes come with OEM bars (i.e. not under an independent brand). I don't know when the bike above is from. If that is indeed an OEM handlebar, then if you know the bike manufacturer, you could already have all the information you're going to get if they have a captive brand. That said, the frame manufacturer might have changed OEM suppliers along the way.

I glanced at random pages on Cannondale and Specialized. A lot of their handlebars are branded to the company itself. They may use a generic, high-volume OEM supplier. I know this happens with wheels a fair bit; companies might spec hubs from Bitex, Novatec, Glory Wheel, or other OEM hub manufacturers. The whole wheel is branded to the wheel company itself, which will offer service parts like freehub bodies and endcaps.

Captive brands exist as well. Roval was a French wheel company which Specialized bought mainly (I believe) for the name. It's now a high-quality captive brand for both wheels and some handlebars and seatposts. While it's under Specialized's corporate structure, they may be staffed independently from Specialized. Bontrager (captive of Trek) and Cadex (captive of Giant) operate this way.

Not everyone has a captive brand or uses generic OEM finishing kit. Santa Cruz bicycles, a smaller mass production firm, specs Easton bars on the [Stigmata gravel line](https://www.santacruzbicycles.com/en-US/bikes/stigmata). I own a Parlee, another small brand which has used the Zipp handlebars and finishing kit I mention above. [Wilier Triestina](https://wilier.com/en/my2023/int/endurance-bikes/road-bikes/superleggera) specs Cinelli handlebars on its Superleggera steel bike. Ritchey, Deda (short for Deda Elementi), 3T, and Thomson are some of the independent handlebar (and other equipment) brands I can remember off the top of my head.

Comment: I would actually to measure any flare, as some people like it and some really don't .  This might not be traditional on road bars but a little flare is becoming quite common on many drop bar bikes (at least the sort I look at - I'm not sure about pure fast road bikes being more about endurance).  Similarly any outsweep though this does tend to be mainly on gravel bars. [Some tips on specifying flare](https://bikepacking.com/index/gravel-bars/)

Comment: @ChrisH it’s unlikely the OP’s bike had flared bars, as they’re a much more recent thing. That said, to measure flare without the original specs, I would probably state the width c-c at the hoods and in the drops. That would probably suffice, although one can work out the flare angle with trigonometry. I’d also state if there was any sweep. And yes, the pic actually depicts a bar with both flare and sweep. Maybe I should’ve chosen a simpler pic but it was the first one to hand.

Comment: we know the bars aren't original from one of the OP's comments, so they could be far more recent than the frame.  However you're probably right as they also describe the bars as compact and compact flared bars are rare